# Как читать данные из Word на языке PHP?

Tags: php, ms-word

Есть ли библиотека для этой задачи?

Я создаю тестирование для университета и мне нужно считать 300 вопросов из Word-а с помощью PHP и дальше записать в MYSQL? Проблема в том, что я не могу прочесть файл Word. Помогите решить задачу! Буду благодарен...

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы нет? Гугл знает все - вот, к примеру: [phpwordlib](http://www.phpwordlib.motion-bg.com/).

Тогда вот этот класс, конвертирует doc и rtf в plain text

или вот вообще) [doc2text](http://obninsk.name/obninsk_doc/) =) Имхо вообще норм должно подойти

Comment: мне нужно читать данные, а писать я могу!

Comment: phpwordlib тогда можно попробовать

Comment: или doc2text =) линк в первом посте

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, вордовские DOC и DOCX - это *псевдо-форматы*. 
На самом деле любой Word файл - это ZIP-архив, состоящий из кучи XML-файлов и изображений, которые вставлены в текст.
Можно поискать библиотеки для работы с XML. Например **SimpleXML** (встроенный) или [XMLReader](http://se.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php)